# Como receber um array de resultados em uma variavel

Tags: php, codeigniter

Bom dia,
Estou tentando realizar um projeto bem simples usando o framework Codeigniter, mas sempre tive essa dúvida antes mesmo de implementar um framework, sempre me bato muito para receber dados que são um array, e mostrar esses resultados na tela para o usuario, geralmente eu realizo uma consulta no banco de dados e quero mostrar esses resultados para o usuario, não tenho conseguido usar com o foreach pois sempre me mostra apenas o ultimo resultado, e quero todos os registros que a consulta ao banco de dados me retornou.
Será que alguém pode me ajudar? ou passar um link para algum artigo sobre o assunto?

Tenho um exemplo que eu mostro para o usuarios os horarios que estão no banco de dados e ele seleciona alguns desses horarios, mas antes de cadastrar os horarios que ele selecionou eu quero que, imptima na tela com echo para confirmar a solicitação do usuario.

MODEL

```
public function select_horarios(){
    $this->db->select('hora');
    $this->db->from('horarios');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query){
        return $query->result_array();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('administrativo/abrirfechar_agenda', 'agenda');



    if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'Abrir Agenda >>'){
        $data = $this->input->post('data');
        $horarios = $this->input->post('horarios');

        //Data Formatada
        $data_form = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data));

        if(empty($data)){
            echo 'Selecione a Data';
        }else if(empty($horarios)){
            echo 'Informe os horarios para a data '.$data_form;
        }else{              
            //INICIANDO A CONSULTA PELA DATA E HORARIOS SELECIONADOS                

            //Tratamento de matriz
            foreach($horarios as $linha){
                $horas = $linha;
            }
            //INICIANDO O CADASTRO NO BD PARA ABERTURA DE AGENDA.
            echo "Passou na validação ".$horas;
            }       
    }

    $dados['horarios'] = $this->agenda->select_horarios();
    $this->load->view('administrativo/abrirfechar_agenda', $dados);
}
```

VIEW

```
echo form_label('Selecione os Horários: ', 'horario');
    echo "</br>";

    foreach($horarios as $linha){           
        echo form_checkbox('horarios[]',$linha['hora']);
        echo $linha['hora'];
        echo "</br>";
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, poste o código que está tentando implementar, desde model, view e controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso, se você vai selecionar quais os usuários selecionou, sem ver a sua view completa, eu faria dessa forma:

```
// controller
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('administrativo/abrirfechar_agenda', 'agenda');
    $dados['horarios'] = $this->agenda->select_horarios();
    $this->load->view('administrativo/abrirfechar_agenda', $dados);
}


// model
public function select_horarios(){

    $this->db->select('hora');
    $query = $this->db->get('horarios')->result();

    if($this->input->post('data') && $this->input->post('horarios')){ // Se houver post data, horarios
        $horarios_selecionados[] = array();
        foreach($query as &$value){ // busco todos os horários
            // neste caso, fazemos então a comparação se existe já o horário cadastrado
            // se sim, ele adiciona na array, para que consigamos dizer ao usuário qual horári
            // já tem cadastrado
            $this->db->where('horario', $value);
            $this->db->where('data', $this->input->post('data'));
            $value->horarios = $this->db->get('horarios')->result();
            $value->data = $this->input->post('data');
        }
    }

    if($query){
        return $query;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

// view
foreach($horarios as $value){
    foreach($value->horarios as $h_selecionado){
        echo $h_selecionado."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Agora para este exemplo consegui mostrar os resultados dos horarios que estão no banco de dados, mas não consigo mostrar na tela os horarios que o usuario selecionou, pois com o código que postei só me mostra o ultimo resultado. e quero todos os horarios que ele selecionou

Comment: Tente dessa forma que lhe passei agora.

Comment: Andre mas esta retornando todos os horarios que o usuario digitou que estão iguais no banco de dados, esta certo mas preciso consultar a data, por exemplo se não dia 02/01/2019 já tiver cadastro do horario 09:00, não posso cadastrar nesta data

Comment: Veja se dá certo da forma que lhe passei... claro que é uma solução superficial, sem ver sua view e nem o banco de dados...

Comment: Dá certo Sim Andre fiz algumas modificações e funcionou perfeitamente, obrigada pela ajuda... como não entendo como funciona o site o que devo fazer para fechar a pergunta já que voce já solucionou minha duvida?

Comment: Você pode votar (seta para cima, na minha resposta, e marcar como correta - V abaixo das setas) obrigado :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89080/discussion-between-sr-andre-baill-and-sol25lua).

Answer (score 1):

Model

```
public function get_all($limit = NULL, $offset = NULL)
{
        $this->db->select('cli_id, cli_nome');
        $this->db->from("cliente");        
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data = $query->result();
        return $data;
}

$results = $this->Cliente_model->get_all_where($limit, $offset);

foreach ($results as $row) {
  echo $row->cli_nome;
}
```

Comment: Este é um exemplo como uso o codeigninter para exibir dados do banco de dados;

Comment: só coloquei o nome da função errada get_all_where -> get_all e Também esqueci de retirar os 2 atributos que não estão sendo utilizados.